# Distribute value over list

Tags: python, list, numpy

Given the amount S=25 and list L = [10,20,30] I want to distribute S over L in the following way:
output -> [10, 15, 0]

I wrote the following code, which does the job:

```
S = 25
l = [10,20,30]
res= []
b = True

for value in l:
    if b == True: 
        if S - value >0:
            res.append(value)
        else:
            res.append(S)
            b= False
        S -= value
    else:
        res.append(0)
```

Is it possible to rewrite it, maybe as a one-liner? (numpy is allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly shorter and more readable:

```
def distribute(S, L):
    res = []
    for e in L:
        res.append(min(e, S))
        S = max(0, S-e)
    return res
```

While you can make this (or anything really) a one-liner, I wouldn't force it. It's better to keep things readable.

You can also use an equivalent generator function:

```
def distribute(S, L):
    for e in L:
        yield min(e, S)
        S = max(0, S-e)

list(distribute(S, l))
```

Comment: I added a (in my opinion) more pythonic generator. Your solution is still very good. +1

Comment: I love the latter one. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

This is one way, but please do not get attached to one-liners for the sake of them being one-liners. Often they are not the best method, either in terms of readability or performance.

```
from itertools import accumulate

S = 25
l = [10, 20, 30]

res = [i if j <= S else max(0, S-k) \
       for i, j, k in zip(l, accumulate(l), accumulate([0]+l))]

# [10, 15, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### numpy

Since OP specifically asked for `numpy`, let's assume this is about large arrays. I think `distribute` in the OP subject was a key word, because this is very similar to conversion between PDF and CDF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) and the inverse:

```py
a = numpy.array([10, 20, 30])
c = a.cumsum()                   # [10, 30, 60]
b = c.clip(0, 25)                # [20, 25, 25]
numpy.ediff1d(b, to_begin=b[0])  # [10, 15, 0]
```